# Kick off a job after manual approval in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a requirement of trigerring a Job B after Job A executes successfully.
After Job A executes successfully , an email notification will be sent to the approver . The approver will receive an email and click on the mail link . He will be routed to Jenkins page where he will approve the execution of Job B .

I am not sure which plugin to use where I can mention the name of the approver , how the approver can click on the link and simple say "approve" after logging in to the Jenkins page.

Comment: could any one check for my question on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46946409/promote-plugin-not-sending-emails-with-promote-url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Setup `Job A`
- Configure `Job A` to send email to your "approver" as part of Email Ext post-build action
- Configure the email to contain link back to the job run (not just job name, or you could even link directly to promotion from the email)
- Configure a **[Promotion](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)** on `Job A`
- In that promotion, allow it to be run only by your "approver" user (by name)
- Configure that promotion to trigger `Job B`

When `Job A` is run, it will send email to "approver". He/she will click the link and come to the Jenkins job run UI. He/she should be logged in to Jenkins with their "approver" user.

Then he/she can click the promotion star and simply click "approve" on it. This will trigger the promotion which in turn triggers `Job B`

Note: you can achieve something similar without "Promotions" plugin, but this is exactly the reason why that plugin exists, so use it.

Comment: Thanks @Slav that is exactly what I was looking for, I am facing an issue , can you please provide your inputs :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078617/promoted-build-plugin-can-not-see-promotions

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the [Jenkins Workflow plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/) (as per the `jenkins-workflow` tag on the question), which is designed for this kind of more complex system. You would write something like (off the top of my head):

`build job: 'A', wait: true
mail to: 'user@…', subject: "Please approve #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", body: """
See ${env.BUILD_URL}input/
"""
input submitter: 'userId', message: 'Ready?'
build job: 'B', wait: true`

Later the `build` steps can be replaced with actual build tasks by inlining the work of those freestyle jobs.

Comment: currently we are exploring this option , Thanks @Jesse