# Promoted Build Plugin , can not see Promotions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I am running the Jenkins Job with promotion setup like below ,

[image]

I cant see my promotions after the build is completed in the UI .

[image]

Please suggest if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Builds that had finished before the promotion was originally created are not "promotable"

Run a new build, and it will show.

Note: this restriction is only on the creation of a new promotion. You can modify the promotion process as much as you need, and it will be executable on older builds without problem (as long as those builds had finished after the original promotion was created)

**Edit:**
I think I misunderstood your question. It appears you are on the "Promotions History" page, the one at `http://$JENKINS_SERVER/$JOB_URL/promotion/`. You won't see builds here until they have been triggered for promotion.

To actually trigger a promotion on a build, you have to select the specific build number/job run. Promotions are per job-run, not per job. Each job run has associated promotions with it.

You need to be at `http://$JENKINS_SERVER/$JOB_URL/123/promotion/` where `123` is the build number that you want to promote. You can use permalinks instead of `123`, such as `lastBuild` or `lastSuccessfulBuild`, etc.

To reference to `123` from within the build (in order to use this in email notification links, etc), you can use `$BUILD_NUMBER` variable.

Through the UI, you need to select a build from the build history, click 
"Promotion Status" there, and then approve/trigger a promotion (I know it's confusing since both "history page" and "trigger/execution" pages have the same name for the link.)

Comment: Edited answer with alternative

Comment: I have tried to build multiple times after creating the promotion . It doesnt show in Promotion Status . Just to let you know, I have configured this promotion within my build job . This option of "promote build when" is right at the start . When I build my job , all the steps which are after this promotion definition are run properly(like calling other project and sending an email) .But this promotion doesnt show up in "Promotion Status"/

Comment: Do you see a red star next to the build run in the build history? Also, it appears you've configured promotions to execute immediately after the build?

Comment: I think i got your point after your edit , Let me try and get back .

Comment: Hey @Slav I have added one more question , whenever u get a chance , please have a look .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082154/parameterize-the-approver-detail-in-promoted-build-plugin-in-jenkins

Answer (score 2):

First you have to promote the build then you can see that particular build in promotion status.
First click on build number that you want to promote then click click on promotion status from late panel. Here you will see the user who can promote the build.
Then you have to approve it for the promotion.