# Parameterize the approver detail in Promoted Build Plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Promote Build plugin in Jenkins .
I need to take the approver information from the user in Jenkins and provide him the approval rights .
Here is what I am trying to do : [image]

Is it feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can use variables there. However, you could skip that condition, and instead have an **Execute Shell** build step, and there check for variables `$PROMOTED_USER_NAME`. Parse the name, and make your decision based on that.

Parent parameters don't automatically get passed to Promoted builds. However, you can export them to file, archive the file (important to archive as opposed to keep it in workspace), bring the file over in the promotion step, and either load it to environment variables with **[EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)** plugin, or simply use the file as is in a script

**On Parent Job**

- Configure parameter `approverid`
- Have an **Execute Shell** build step with the following:
  `echo approverid=$approverid > myfile`
- At the end, make sure to **Archive** `myfile`

**On Promotion Configuration**

- Skip the approval criteria
- Add [**Copy Artifacts from another project**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) step
- For *Project Name*, use `$PROMOTED_JOB_NAME`
- For *Which build*, use *Specific Build*, then provide `$PROMOTED_NUMBER`
- For *Artifacts to copy*, use `myfile`
- Add [**Inject Environment Variables**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) build step
- For *Properties File Path*, enter `myfile`
- Add **Execute Shell** build step
- In that shell, compare values of `$approverid` and `$PROMOTED_USER_NAME`
- If they match, continue, else abort/exit promotion.

Or course, the history of execution (and abort) will be noted however.